# Jenkins How to find the build number of the upstream build from downstream

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have two jobs in Jenkins:

1. Job A: Build source + run unit tests, triggered by SCM changes. This is fast. It doesn't trigger anything by itself
2. Job B: Build installer. This takes some time. It is triggered by monitoring successful builds of job A ("Build after other projects are built"). 
   It uses artifacts from job A.

It can happen that several job A builds are started while a single run of Job B is in progress.

```
Job A #1 -> triggers Job B #1
                  |
Job A #2          |
                  |
Job A #3  -.      ` Job B #1 finishes
            `-> triggers Job B #2
Job A #4          |
                  |
Job A #5          |
 |                ` Job B #2 finishes
  `-----------> triggers job B #3
```

My question is: How can I figure out what build number of A triggered a certain build number of B, so in job B I can copy the artifacts from that exact build of job A?

The 'Copy Artifact' plugin allows specifying a specific build number, but where do I get it from?

Comment: I think you should be able to do another method too. You can probably find the last build number with groovy in regards to your upstream build, increment it, and assign that value to a dynamic parameter. That means it would be a number generated at build-queue and as long as it's forwarded downstream, should remain the same when needing to reference it.

Comment: I need to do this other way around. I need to pass the build numbers of downstream job to upstream job. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

One of least cumbersome and cheap ways to do this:
you could pass the `A` `${BUILD_NUMBER}` environment variable to `B` by using [Parametrized Build plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build). For example, define `PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER` variable in B and the pass `PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER` from `A` to `B`.

Answer (score 5):

Of course the option was right there in the Copy Artifact plugin...

[image]

Comment: While this looks like a perfect solution found by you for you, I can add that you could get pass the 'A' ${BUILD_NUMBER} environment variable to the 'B' by using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build. Just the PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER parameter to downstream job call.

Comment: @Zloj You should make your comment an answer. It answers the question I had, because my linked jobs are not using artefacts.

Comment: @PatrickB. done. Must have been in a hurry back when I left the comment. I barely could understand what I wrote myself :D

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me without having to use a plugin using curl/ruby. You may need to generate an API key and pass that in to auth.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

info = `curl -qs http://localhost:8080/job/#{ENV['JOB_NAME']}/#{ENV['BUILD_NUMBER']}/api/json`

puts JSON.parse(info)['actions'].first['causes'].first['upstreamBuild']
```

Take look at info it has all the info you'd need from the upstream job.